# Using another third party application in existing application in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi I have created an application . is it possible to integrate another already developed third party application in mine so I can make  use of some of its features ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android applications are **"sandboxed**". So, yo cannot integrate any third party application into your application. At the maximum you can launch that any third party application from your application if that application allows it. Also you can launch some of its specific features, if the application has set intent filter for them and you know them.